# Do I need a visa in New Delhi?

Tags: visas, india, transit-visas, new-delhi, lithuanian-citizens

Good day, my name is Arvydas! I am Lithuanian.

Here is a quick overview of my trip.

Riga - Kiev - New Delhi - Kathmandu

Riga - Kiev  (Ukraine International Airlines)

Kiev - New Delhi  (Ukraine International Airlines)

New Delhi - Kathmandu  (IndiGo Airlines)

I am flying on 7th of February from Kiev (Ukraine) to Dew Delhi (India).

When I land in New Delhi at 7:20 AM on 8th of Febryary I will have to collect and recheck my baggage because I will be travelling with different airlines to my last destination which is Kathmandu (Nepal) at 11:40 AM on 8th of February. So I am spending 4 hours at the airport.

I was wondering, since I will be rechecking my luggage, do I need some sort of Indian visa to do that? Normal visa? E-visa or a transit visa would be efficient?

Really looking forward to your answer, since I am really confused, I get a lot of different opinions from various sources.

Thank you and have a nice day!

Best,

Arvydas

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I have called to this institution - http://www.indianconsulate.lt/index.php/lt/apie-mus/indijos-ambasada and I have found out that in my case I **would** need a transit visa.

However, since my trip is in less than 15 days (7th of February, now it is 28th January)  and the transit visa could only be issued in 2 weeks or so (I can not do all the paperwork online, I have to fill some papers by hand, send them to Vilnius (Lithuania), then they would send my documents to Warsaw (Poland) and back to me) it takes too much time and it is risky if I would get visa in time.

Therefore I was recommended to purchase India tourist visa (e-visa) here: https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/evisa/tvoa.html and that will work for me.

I will probably choose the shortest period that I can get for this visa, since I don't want to pay a lot (planning to spend only 4 hours in Indian airport...). Or, of course, I can sneak a trip to India as well during my visit to Nepal since I will already have an Indian visa. ;)

Anyway, hope it helps someone.

Have a nice trip!